# validation for ng-multiselect-dropdown in angular 5

Tags: angular

I use multi-select dropdown in my application using this npm "ng-multiselect-dropdown". I want to create the validation for this multiselect (template driven form)

[ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)

Anyone suggest me how to do the validation?

Answer (score 3):

html

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown 
        formControlName="vendorList" id="vendorList" [data]="vendorNameList"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedVendor" [settings]="vendorListDropdownSettings"
        >
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
<div *ngIf="submitted && formGroup.controls['vendorList'].invalid" 
        class="text-danger mt-1">
      <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls['vendorList'].errors.required">
        Vendor Name is required.
      </div>
    </div>
```

typescript

```
vendorList: ["", Validators.required],
```

Answer (score 0):

`html`

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': address.controls['district'].status==='INVALID'}"
style="padding: 0;"
formControlName="district"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

`type script`

```
district: ["", Validators.required],
```